# Does this piece of code leak memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

So I was having an argument with a friend, and what better way to settle it than SO?

Take for instance the following simplified example. Assume all the other functions are implemented correctly. Does this copy constructor leak memory?

My position is that it most definitely doesn't. It's allocating `[rhs._size]` memory for the new object, that is deallocated in the destructor when the object goes out of scope, and the memory allocated for `rhs` is deallocated in its own respective destructor.

```
template<typename T>
class dynarray
{
private:
    T* _data;
    std::size_t _size;

public:
    dynarray(const dynarray& rhs)
        : _data(new T[rhs._size]), _size(rhs._size)
    {
        std::copy(rhs._data, rhs._data + rhs._size, _data);
    }

    ~dynarray() { delete[] _data; }
};
```

Comment: Why does your friend think it leaks memory? I don't think it will, but looks susceptible to double frees due to missing the assignment operator (just use vector).

Comment: So noob to question but, how do you use this class?(declare, usage, purpose)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can leak memory.

You'll have a memory leak if `std::copy` throws an exception.  This can happen if an element assignment throws.  All this depends on `T` and the state of `rhs`.

Specifically you'll leak memory if, for any non-negative integer `n < rhs._size`, the following throws:

```
 *(_data + n) = *(rhs._data + n);
```

Comment: To fix it, use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` instead of `T*` as the type of the internal array.  This also eliminates the need for a user-defined destructor, and makes copy assignment default to deleted instead of broken.

Comment: Fair point. I've deleted my answer because I think yours is more technically correct.

Yeah, `T`'s copy c'tor could be `noexcept`, or not, so it depends.